# How can to retrieve and write the BLOB in my storage in oracle

Tags: oracle, blob

I have a table with this script:

```
CREATE TABLE PRSNL_IMG
(
  PER_IMG       LONG RAW,
  NATIONAL_COD  NUMBER
);
```

Now I want to retrieve and write  the BLOB (  PER_IMG  type: LONG RAW )  into a file with name  `"NATIONAL_COD"`  on path on hard sush as *"D:\Photo_OUT\"*  from the database with name .My table have 82000 records.I have work with form6i and my database version is oracle 11g.
please help me.

Comment: Please provide code of what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with BLOB like this

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE foo (
    b BLOB);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('1f8b080087cdc1520003f348cdc9c9d75128cf2fca49d1e30200d7bbcdfc0e000000');
```

and just select it

```
SELECT b FROM foo;
-- (BLOB)

SELECT UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(b))
FROM foo;
-- 1F8B080087CDC1520003F348CDC9C9D75128CF2FCA49D1E30200D7BBCDFC0E000000
```

If the content is not too large, you can also use

```
SELECT CAST ( <blobfield> AS RAW( <maxFieldLength> ) ) FROM <table>;
```

Comment: hi, i have a table full of images and now download them on  my computer with the name national_code (another item) for every record  .

Comment: but atleast provide some code if you have done already or which programming language are you planning to use?

Comment: i use pl/sql language

Comment: I am really not able to understand your question.

Comment: We have Oracle 11g 
I have a table temp_photo 
Name     Null     Type 
---------- -------- ------------ 
PER_IMG       LONG RAW,
NATIONAL_COD  NUMBER

I have inserted a .jpg file into the LONG RAW. 
I now need to create a PL/SQL procedure to extract the data from the LONG RAW and store the file on my local drive. 
Can anyone please help? 
Your help would be very much appreciated.